# Dataframe definition for range based grouping not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to plot a treemap. However, the way I want to define the borders of each treemap class is based on a range rather than by a single number. The exmaple I am working of uses a single number.

Here is the code where it is specified:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nb_people':[8,3,4,2], 'group':["group A", "group B", "group C", "group D"] })
```

Instead, I want to group like this:
Group A: 0-2
Group B: 3-5
Group C: >6

I was not able to find a solution which incorporates the range based grouping in the dataframe definition. I hope somebody can guide. Thank you in advance.

```
pip install squarify
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import squarify   


MODIFY THIS PART! df = pd.DataFrame({'nb_people':[8,3,4,2], 'group':["group A", "group B", "group C", "group D"] })

squarify.plot(sizes=df['nb_people'], label=df['group'], alpha=.8 )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separately provide the array to use in the DataFrame definition itself.

```
nb =[8,3,4,2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'nb_people':nb, 'group':["GROUP A" if 0 <= x <= 2 else "GROUP B" if 3 <= x <= 5 else "GROUP C" if x > 6 else "NO_GROUP" for x in nb]})
```

You can also load the 'nb_people' column and then use apply function. This is more **readable**.

```
def my_func(row):
    if 0 <= row <= 2:
        return "GROUP A"
    elif 3 <= row <= 5:
        return "GROUP B"
    elif row > 6:
        return "GROUP C"
    else:
        return "NO_GROUP"

df = pd.DataFrame({'nb_people':[8,3,4,2]})

df['group'] = df['nb_people'].apply(myfunc)
```

output (for both ways)

```
df

    nb_people   group
0   8       GROUP C
1   3       GROUP B
2   4       GROUP B
3   2       GROUP A
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby and [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
intervals=df.groupby(pd.cut(df["nb_people"], np.array([0,2,5,np.inf]),include_lowest=True,labels=['Group A','Group B','Group C'])).groups
```

---

```
squarify.plot(sizes=df['nb_people'], label=intervals, alpha=.8)
plt.show()
```

Output image:

[image]